# How to make menu items fill the top bar

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I recently switched from Bootstrap to Foundation, just for the top-navigation bar. I'd like to set the menu items to always adjust accordingly and fill the bar at all times.
A bootstrap example is available here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html

In this example, no matter how many items exist in the menu, they always adjust their width accordingly so that the nav bar is always filled.
How do I achieve such thing in Foundation?

Comment: not sure that example works very well. When i resize my browser I loose half the options in the menu. http://d.pr/i/AoM5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to count the number of `li` and set the width of each `li` to the appropriate %.

So 8 list items each one would be 12.5%;

JQuery

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.autowidth = function() {
    return this.each(function() {        
        $('li', this).css({'width' : (100 / $('li', this).length) + '%'})
    });
  };
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav > ul').autowidth();    
});
```

[**CODEPEN DEMO.**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oHLsj)

Add & Remove list items to see it work.